# Update to run php file from asp.net C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my project I want to call php file . But it is showing an error **"405 method not allowed"** .
Please help me !!!

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/index.php",
    data: "{}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the GET method instead of POST.

Comment: Thnaks a lot ........